# Check table if there is fields if not create one if so edit it?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to make a button that adds data to a table. Though I only want to be working with one field.

I use this atm:

```
rec.AddNew
rec("WorkOrder") = Me.ProjectAddWorkOrderTxt
rec.Update
```

With 3 different buttons that change 3 other columns in that field. Every time I push the button to add the information into the table, it creates a new field with the data under the correct column. Why is obvious, because the rec.AddNew. It creates a new field.

Is there a way to check if there is a field in the table yet, and if so it just edits that one field and if not it creates a new one?

There is a main form with 5 buttons on it; which pop up 5 different forms. These forms have 1 text box and 1 button. None of the forms are bound to any record sources.

What I want is for you to be able to enter data into the text box, and it adds that data to the temp form when you push that 1 button. At the same time it closes the form down revealing the main one again.

Then, when I push another button on the main form it grabs all the information currently on the temptable, and puts it into the maintable. Then it deletes all data on the temptable.

--

This is the full code for the button with the answer's below additon

```
Private Sub ProjectWorkOrderBackBtn_Click()

Dim db As Database
Dim rec As DAO.Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rec = db.OpenRecordset("Select * from ProjectsTempT")

rec.FindFirst "WorkOrder='" & Me.ProjectAddWorkOrderTxt.Value & "'"

If (rec.NoMatch) Then
  rec.AddNew
Else
  rec.Edit
End If

rec("WorkOrder").Value = Me.ProjectAddWorkOrderTxt.Value
rec.Update

Set rec = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
Me.ProjectAddWorkOrderTxt = Null
DoCmd.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Please tell us about the context --- is this a bound or unbound form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please test this if it works ?

```
Private Sub ProjectWorkOrderBackBtn_Click()

  Dim db As Database
  Dim rec As DAO.Recordset

  Set db = CurrentDb
  Set rec = db.OpenRecordset("ProjectsTempT", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)

  'On Error Resume Next

  '
  'rec.FindFirst "WorkOrder='" & Me.ProjectAddWorkOrderTxt.Value & "'"
  '

  If (rec.EOF) Then
    rec.AddNew
  Else
    rec.Edit
  End If

  rec("WorkOrder").Value = Me.ProjectAddWorkOrderTxt.Value
  rec.Update

  Set rec = Nothing
  Set db = Nothing

  'On Error Goto 0

  '
  'Me.ProjectAddWorkOrderTxt = Null
  'DoCmd.Close
  '
End Sub
```

The table ProjectsTempT must exist.

Comment: Seems to not work and instead does exactly the same thing as before. It creates a new record every time I open the form,e dit the text field, and push the button. It doesn't replace the current information in the 1 field, and if I open a different text box in another form that adds/should edit another column in that field, it just adds a new field and puts the data in the respective column.

Comment: rec should be a DAO.Recordset from the same underlying table for each button action, I don't know your data structure... How they are saved.

Comment: So I should not use this? `Set rec = db.OpenRecordset("Select * from ProjectsTempT")` as that is what I used for rec.

Comment: This is a DAO.Recordset... shall work. If you have difficulties, please post more code in your question by updating it.

Comment: I changed it to `Dim rec As DAO.Recordset` though now it doesn't even enter the data onto the table. I'm sorry, I am probably doing something wrong... I really haven't used DAO.Recordsets before.

Comment: That did not work. "Run-time error '3021': No current record.

It highlights this line:
`rec.FindFirst "WorkOrder='" & Me.ProjectAddWorkOrderTxt.Value & "'"`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41035/discussion-between-d347hxd-and-jacouh)

Answer (score 1):

You could also pare the code a little bit, which would also increase your response time.

```
Private Sub ProjectWorkOrderBackBtn_Click()

Dim db As Database
Dim rec As DAO.Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rec = db.OpenRecordset("Select * from ProjectsTempT WHERE WorkOrder='" & Me.ProjectAddWorkOrderTxt.Value & "'")

If rec.EOF = "True" Then
  rec.AddNew
Else
  rec.Edit
End If

rec("WorkOrder").Value = Me.ProjectAddWorkOrderTxt.Value
rec.Update

Set rec = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
Me.ProjectAddWorkOrderTxt = Null
DoCmd.Close
End Sub
```

Keep in mind that Access is Client Side, which means it pulls the entire dataset to your local machine before performing a function.  Reducing the size of that dataset will speed up the process, so just bring in the records you need instead of pulling the whole table and doing a FindFirst.